# SVN analysis tool

Tags: svn, code-analysis

I have been searching all over the net to find something remotely usable. I tried all kinds of HTML based tools for analyzing an SVN repository (commits by users, reports etc) but none of them are user friendly.

I am interested in a desktop client (that does NOT depend on an external svn.exe to be installed on my system) that does just that. Analyze the repository and create reports.

Does anyone know of such a program?

Comment: Are you interested in code-analysis or repository-analysis?

Comment: From my understanding he is interested in repository analysis (like commits by users etc)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can look into  [statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/) which just needs a checkedout workingcopy and a connection to the repo. It will extract tons of informations out of your repository. It is a java project and will run on all architectures. It will also create heatmaps, LOC-graphs and other images to visualize the data.

Comment: I was curious if it would still work, but unfortunately it only works up to SVN 1.3.0:
`Nov 18, 2023 2:30:28 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger error
SCHWERWIEGEND: Subversion binary is incorrect version. Found: 1.14.2, required: 1.3.0`

Answer (score 6):

I tryed [svnplot](https://bitbucket.org/nitinbhide/svnplot/wiki/Home) on a large repository, it generates nice HTML reports with the following graphs:

- Lines of Code vs time
- Lines of Code per author vs time
- Average file size vs time
- File count vs time
- File types histogram
- File changes vs time
- Directories size pie chart
- Commits vs time
- Commits per days of week histogram
- Commits per hours histogram
- Time between commits
- Add/Modify/Delete ratio per user
- Developer activity over time (date and hours, one dot per commit)

It requires Python and a few Python libs.

Comment: Code repository of svnplot can be found here now: https://github.com/nitinbhide/svnplot

Answer (score 4):

TortoiseSVN can show you some, well, basic [statistics](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-5).

Answer (score 1):

I've used StatSVN also. It does provide useful stats (have a look at an example output for [Ant](http://www.statsvn.org/demo/ant/)), but it does require you to have already done a svnlog of the repository and have a working copy checked out to perform the analysis on.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful: https://github.com/dsw/svn-dump-tools

The Queensland Australia police once used it for something, but I don't know what.

```
                        SVN Dump Tools
                     Daniel S. Wilkerson
```

File svn-dumpfile-grammar.txt is documentation for the grammar of an
svn dumpfile.

Tools svn-dump2dir and svn-dir2dump are utilities for easily hacking
on the history of a subversion repository.

Tool simple-patch is a simpler version of patch that you can control
much more easily than Larry Wall's patch (written in Perl; I can hear
Larry screaming).

All software is released under the BSD license, which you can find in
each program file.