# how to get commited row counts from svn

Tags: svn, version

I need to get the number of lines committed by every user in the command mode. I am using rabbit SVN in Ubuntu machine. Can anyone help me on getting this

i used the following syntax to export the commited files as XML.
svn log -v --xml svnpath > /home/admin/Desktop/project.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN analysis tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960213/svn-analysis-tool)

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure that it'll work with rabbit SVN, but [this site](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2787/prints-total-line-count-contribution-per-user-for-an-svn-repository) suggests the following oneliner:

`svn ls -R | egrep -v -e "\/$" | xargs svn blame | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`

Comment: where i have to provide the SVN path in the above syntax. And also i need to get for all the files under the directory

Comment: I would guess that you'd stand in your SVN repository when you run this command - or in the particular sub-directory of your repository that you're interested in (I use GIT myself so I can't try it out).