# Find percent of lines commited SVN

Tags: java, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN analysis tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960213/svn-analysis-tool)

In SVN, how can I get output like this

```
username1    12.4%
username2    97.6%
```

where it means that username1 has contributed (committed) 12.4% of the code and username2 has contributed 97.6% of the code, and I want it to only compute this for .java files (hence, ignore image uploads and things)

How can I do?

Comment: As an aside: Be aware that if I throw out 1000 lines of bad code (-) and add in 30 lines of good code (+30 = -970).... I don't expect to be thought of negatively due to my lower or even negative percentage.... `loc` may be nice to determine ownership, but not for effort.

Comment: @Wrikken so very true. Commited Number of Lines should not be considered to be an exact metric for measuring human performance since different problems require different approaches and thus they produce different results. And then you need to add the human factor. This could however be used as a quantitative code metric.
When measuring humans in my opinion we should be very careful on how we do it. 
There was some info that in the early days Microsoft used to pay "per line of code". We all know how badly this ended for the Windows OS line... ;)

Comment: Why don't people just answer the question? I simply wanted to know how to do it. Why I need to do is doesn't matter for anyone's purposes on this website. I'm not using it as a metric. I'm not stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StatSVN this worked for years for me.

Comment: I really appreciate that you just answered the question and weren't difficult like just about everyone else. Thanks!! This worked perfectly for me.